# How to know check is AutoCompleteTextView showing dropdown or not?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I would like to know a way that somehow can check if AutoCompleteTextView is showing result suggestions or not when the user give the input? is there a way for that?

Comment: Tap on AutoCompleteTextView and type something matches with values and see if work or not

Comment: yup, emm but how you can check it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [AutoCompeleteTextView#isPopupShowing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#isPopupShowing()) method

Comment: yup you are right!!. i test it and it works